# How do I completely remove Xen or at least stop these errors from occurring?

Tags: linux, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, xen, kernel-module

I installed the `xen-hypervisor` package but that froze my system, and didn't know how to solve it so I compiled from source.
That exhibited the same issue so I assumed it was hardware related, and switched (sucessfully) to KVM.

The problem is that now, despite running `make uninstall`  from xen's source dir, there appear to be many remnants of xen left on the system, and I can't find a good resource on scrubbing it out.
I wouldn't mind except I think it's now the cause of this issue (the outputs of `systemctl status systemd-modules-load` and `journalctl _PID=3898`):

```
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX XXXX; Xs ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 3898 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3898 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_evtchn': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_gntdev': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_gntalloc': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_blkback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_netback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_pciback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FA
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

and

```
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_evtchn': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_gntdev': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_gntalloc': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_blkback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_netback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to insert 'xen_pciback': No such device
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'evtchn'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'gntdev'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'netbk'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'blkbk'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'xen-scsibk'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'usbbk'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'pciback'
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Module 'xen_acpi_processor' is builtin
May XX XX:XX:XX dev systemd-modules-load[3898]: Failed to find module 'blktap2'
```

I did look for errant module loading lines in `/etc/modules` (the only module conf, ref'd by symlink from `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`), but there's only `vhost_net` for KVM's network bridge.

**Edit:** I have stopped the errors (by removing `/usr/local/lib/modules-load.d/xen.conf` and restarting the service) but not cleaned up.
Found this list of files modified around the install time but don't recognise all of them.

Any ideas about whether any of these can be safely removed?

```
/boot/xenpolicy-4.8.1
/etc/perl
/etc/perl/XML
/etc/perl/XML/SAX
/etc/texmf
/etc/texmf/texmf.d
/etc/texmf/web2c
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/etc/xen.old-1493602948/scripts/hotplugpath.sh
/usr/local/bin/xenalyze
/usr/local/bin/xen-cpuid
/usr/local/lib/fs/ext2fs/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/fat/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/iso9660/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/reiserfs/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/ufs/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/xfs/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/fs/zfs/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/libblktapctl.a
/usr/local/lib/libblktapctl.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libfsimage.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libvhd.a
/usr/local/lib/libvhd.so.1.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libxencall.a
/usr/local/lib/libxencall.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libxenevtchn.a
/usr/local/lib/libxenevtchn.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libxenforeignmemory.a
/usr/local/lib/libxenforeignmemory.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libxengnttab.a
/usr/local/lib/libxengnttab.so.1.1
/usr/local/lib/libxenlight.a
/usr/local/lib/libxenlight.so.4.8.0
/usr/local/lib/libxenstat.a
/usr/local/lib/libxenstat.so.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libxentoollog.a
/usr/local/lib/libxentoollog.so.1.0
/usr/local/lib/libxenvchan.a
/usr/local/lib/libxenvchan.so.4.8.0
/usr/local/lib/modules-load.d/xen.conf
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxenbus_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxenctrl_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxeneventchn_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxenlight_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxenmmap_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/stublibs/dllxentoollog_stubs.so
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/libxenbus_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.cmo
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenbus/xenbus.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/libxenctrl_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/xenctrl.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/xenctrl.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/xenctrl.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/xenctrl.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenctrl/xenctrl.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/libxeneventchn_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/xeneventchn.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/xeneventchn.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/xeneventchn.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/xeneventchn.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xeneventchn/xeneventchn.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/libxenlight_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/xenlight.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/xenlight.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/xenlight.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/xenlight.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenlight/xenlight.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/libxenmmap_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/xenmmap.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/xenmmap.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/xenmmap.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/xenmmap.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenmmap/xenmmap.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.cmo
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xenstore/xenstore.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/libxentoollog_stubs.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/META
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/xentoollog.a
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/xentoollog.cma
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/xentoollog.cmi
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/xentoollog.cmx
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/4.02.3/xentoollog/xentoollog.cmxa
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fsimage.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xen/lowlevel/xc.so
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xen/lowlevel/xs.so
/usr/local/sbin/flask-get-bool
/usr/local/sbin/flask-getenforce
/usr/local/sbin/flask-label-pci
/usr/local/sbin/flask-loadpolicy
/usr/local/sbin/flask-set-bool
/usr/local/sbin/flask-setenforce
/usr/local/sbin/gdbsx
/usr/local/sbin/img2qcow
/usr/local/sbin/kdd
/usr/local/sbin/lock-util
/usr/local/sbin/oxenstored
/usr/local/sbin/qcow2raw
/usr/local/sbin/qcow-create
/usr/local/sbin/tap-ctl
/usr/local/sbin/tapdisk2
/usr/local/sbin/tapdisk-client
/usr/local/sbin/tapdisk-diff
/usr/local/sbin/tapdisk-stream
/usr/local/sbin/td-util
/usr/local/sbin/xl
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig/xenlight.pc
/usr/local/share/pkgconfig/xlutil.pc
/var/lib/libxml-sax-perl
/var/lib/libxml-sax-perl/ParserDetails.d/10-XML::SAX::PurePerl
/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.3
/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.4
/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.5
```

Comment: I really should have used `checkinstall`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the package from following command.

apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-amd64 / apt-get remove centos-release-xen

or

apt-get purge xen-hypervisor-amd64 / apt-get purge centos-release-xen

Comment: What makes you think OP is running CentOS? They tagged the post with ubuntu-16.04

Comment: I removed the packaged version before installing from source. There are no xen-related packages on the server.